# regular expression - remove space in front of pattern

Tags: regex, vim

I have text as

```
Bla ~ \cite{} and Bla1 ~ \ref{} and Equation in ~ \eqref{}.
```

and I would like to remove spaces between `~` and `\`.
Thus above line, should look like:

```
Bla ~\cite{} and Bla1 ~\ref{} and Equation in ~\eqref{}.
```

I tried following reg. expression `%s:\(\|~\):(~\):gce`

but it replaces replaces empty space with `~`.
Any suggestions for fix?

Comment: What tool are you using? Vim?

Comment: This doesn't need a regular expression. Just replace the string ```~ \ ``` with ```~\ ```

Comment: That is unless there are multiple spaces.

Comment: yes, I am using vim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
:%s/\v(\~)\s+(\\)/\1\2/g
```

Here,

- `\v` enables very magic mode
- `(\~)` - Group 1: `~` char
- `\s+` - one or more whitespaces
- `(\\)` - Group 2: a `\` char
- `\1\2` - the replacement is Group 1 + Group 2 values
- `g` - multiple occurrences.

Comment: Why capture something in a group that is statically known anyway? The replacement can simply be ``\~\\`` (because you are only ever capturing `~` and ``\``)

Comment: @knittl To show how it is possible to extend it in future

Answer (score 1):

I just verified in vim and you only have to make sure to disable the special meaning of `~` in both the pattern and the replacement:

```
:%s/\~ \\/\~\\/g
```

Will replace `~ \` everywhere with `~\` without space.

Comment: Sorry [@Knittl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/112968/knittl) I intende to improve my answer and ended up editing your's. As you can see my approach was a little bit different.

Answer (score 0):

Using vim start match `\zs`

```
:%s/\~\zs //g
```

This means that vim will consider everything after `~` as it patter for substitution, in our case the space. As we are using the `g` flag, vim will change all occurrences in the line.

Answer (score 0):

Using vim start match `\zs`

```
:%s/\~\zs //g
```

This means that vim will consider everything after `~` as it patter for substitution, in our case the space.